# What Keras loss function to use for ternary classification?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, categorical-data, loss-function

My LSTM input samples consist of real numbers in [-1, 1] range and the targets (categories) are -1, 0 and 1.

I've chosen sparse_categorical_crossentropy for the loss function but it seems it doesn't support negative numbers - it says "InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of -1 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1)" when I start training.

What loss function should I use instead for this task?

I also can't understand why does it say [0, 1) which means a number equal or higher than zero but smaller than 1 AFAIK but [what I've read](https://jovianlin.io/cat-crossentropy-vs-sparse-cat-crossentropy/) about sparse_categorical_crossentropy says it's meant to support any integer number.

Answer (score 1):

Your targets have to be integers from `0` to `num_classes - 1`, they can't be negative numbers, as you are doing classification. This is kind of the standard for multi-class classification and you have to follow it.

Also make sure that your last layer outputs 3 numbers with a softmax activation, which will represent a distribution over classes.